# NSData - Write to temporary file / directory

Tags: ios, swift3, nsdata, uiactivityviewcontroller, ckasset

I am a little lost on my quest to -

1. Download a CKAsset (PDF File)
2. Assign a Temporary Filename
3. Write the contents of the CKAsset to the filename

I have managed to download the CKAsset and display the contents in a UIWebView, however I am stumbling over steps 2 and 3, I have a filename from a String, and despite trying a variety of WriteToFile combinations I receive errors.

My code is thus :

```
let filename = record.object(forKey: "materialsFilename")

                        if  materialsType == "PDF" || materialsType == "pdf" {


                            if let asset1 = record.object(forKey: "materialsFile") as? CKAsset {
                                let doc1Data : NSData? = NSData(contentsOf:asset1.fileURL)

                                let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(filename as! String)


                                let contentsOfFile = doc1Data
                                var error: NSError?

                                // Write File
                                if contentsOfFile.writeToFile(path, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8, error: &error) == false {
                                    if let errorMessage = error {
                                        print("Failed to create file")
                                        print("\(errorMessage)")
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    print("File \(filename) created at tmp directory")
                                }
```

This version presents the error -

> Cannot invoke 'writeToFile' with an argument list of type '(URL?,
>   atomically: Bool, encoding: String.Encoding, error: inout NSError?)'

The temporary file once created will be passed to a UIActivityViewController, to print / email / airdrop the PDF, having only a CKAsset name, the the UIActivityViewController cannot associate the file type to any of the users installed apps, save for print.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint before "contentsOfFile.writeToFile"? -> What value does "path" have. If its null, it will not work to write to the specific file. Maybe te filename is somehow wrong ? The other option: Set breakpoint at the end. What does "error" contain?

Comment: The path at that stage appears to be the CKAsset path - 

path=~/Library/Caches/CloudKit/48e71b0c5ca5e4eb9add0599a376bae1d958ed3e/Assets/40118308-8136-4A66-8321-66AD609798A6.01707e7ffadfd047f02bc4a1579e6bcd2dbadf2c0b, size=268270, UUID=40118308-8136-4A66-8321-66AD609798A6, signature=<01707e7f fadfd047 f02bc4a1 579e6bcd 2dbadf2c 0b

Comment: Are you allowed to write to the Cloud / use the iCloud of the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little head scratching and reviewing my choices following the pointers above, I changed tack and didn't really need to write to a file, just rename the CKAsset, which I achieved with the following script -

```
let materialsType = record.object(forKey: "materialsType") as! String

                        let filename = record.object(forKey: "materialsFilename") as! String

                        if  materialsType == "PDF" || materialsType == "pdf" {

                            if let asset1 = record.object(forKey: "materialsFile") as? CKAsset {

                                let doc1Data : Data? = Data(contentsOf:asset1.fileURL) as Data?
                                let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(filename)
                                self.materialsWebView.load(doc1Data! as Data, mimeType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: NSURL() as URL)
                                self.filenameURL = [(fileURL)]
                            }
```

The key seemed to hinge on two lines -

```
let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(filename)
```

and

```
self.filenameURL = [(fileURL)]
```

Which generates the filename for the UIActivityViewController and thus opens up the access to a number of additional Apps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using the correct `writeToFile` method? The `NSData` [reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata?language=objc#symbols) doesn't show a method with the same signature you're using. Try using one of the ones listed in the reference.

Answer (score 0):

I only find the following function in Data class.

```
func write(to: URL, options: Data.WritingOptions)
```

Try this.

Comment: And I suggest you use Data rather than NSData in Swift 3.